# Kendo UI Diagram ,SVG scrollbar and height issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

Hi trying to use the kendo diagram and the implementation code is in the dojo https://dojo.telerik.com/IriSAmoR/8 . When you zoom the image using the mouse, the image is hiding in the top /bottom and not able to see the full image. its fine if the scroll on both sides to see the image. attached the image when its zoomed.

Let me know how to view the full image?. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The zoom and un-zoom function (I am presuming you are mouse-hovering and thumb-wheel scrolling) is an affine transformation centered at the mouse position.  You could add a button for resetting the diagram.

See this [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/UWecAMuS/2), which has

```
<input id="reset" type="button" value="reset" class="k-button">
```

and

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      createDiagram();
      $("#reset").kendoButton({
        click: function() {
          var diagram = $("#diagram").getKendoDiagram();          
            diagram.bringIntoView(diagram.shapes);
        },
      });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your response.but i donot want to reset the image.

Answer (score 0):

found a way to get the expected behaviour what i need.here is the dojo https://dojo.telerik.com/IriSAmoR/11.

The below code is the fix.

```js
                 zoomRate: 0,
                dataBound: function () {
                    var bbox = this.boundingBox();
                    this.wrapper.width(bbox.width + bbox.x + 50);
                    this.wrapper.height(bbox.height + bbox.y + 50);
                    this.resize();
                },
```